# antminer u3 what can they mine? noob alert

Tags: mining-hardware

I'm very new to the mining world and I was wondering if they mine other currencies such as Ethereum and Dubai coin?

Comment: USB miners are a thing of the past I'm sorry to say. The U3 is an ASIC SHA256 miner, so it can mine any coin that uses the SHA256 mining algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You can only mine altcoins that use the SHA 256 algo.

1. BTCitcoin(Its funny to write about bitcoin bcoz everyone know this)
2. 21Coin (21)
3. Peercoin (PPC)
4. Namecoin (NMC)
5. Unobtanium (UNO)
6. Deutsche eMark (DEM)
7. Betacoin (BET)
8. Bytecoin (BTE)
9. Joulecoin (XJO)

10.Devcoin (DVC)

11.Ixcoin (IXC)

12.Terracoin (TRC)

13.Battlecoin (BCX)

14.Takeicoin (TAK)

15.PetroDollar (P$)

16.PremineCoin (PMC) {Premined, Mine only tx Fees}

17.Benjamins (BEN)

18.Globe (GLB)

19.Unicoin (UNIC)

20.Snowcoin (SNC)

see https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=482002.0